# Rollback to specific version of a python package in Goolge Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, version

I've read that

> rolling back rpy2 version to v3.4.2 fixed the problem

(in this case [Rpy2 Error depends on execution method: NotImplementedError: Conversion "rpy2py" not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74192490/rpy2-error-depends-on-execution-method-notimplementederror-conversion-rpy2py), but it could be any problem)

How can I change the installed version of the python package `rpy2` to version v3.4.2 in Google Colab? I know the command `!pip install rpy2`, but how can I chose a specific version and is it a problem if there is already a newer version installed?

In other words: How can I downgrade the version of a python package in Google Colab?

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install -Iv rpy2==3.4.2
```

worked for me as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226504/7735095